# When I am logged into mysql how do I change to different database?

Tags: mysql, database

When in Mysql what command changes to a different database without having to log out?

I log in to a database with:

```
mysql -u root -p database
```

Then to change databases I exit and log back in:

```
mysql -u root -p other_database
```

Is there anyway shortcut to do this without logging out?

Answer (score 5):

You use the command:

```
use [db_name];
```